# announcement tiles web part doesn't show toolbar

Tags: web-part, toolbar, announcement-tiles, announcements

So I've been playing around with all of the different web parts that can be added OOTB in SharePoint 2016 and I tried adding an Announcement Tiles web part to see how it is different from just an Announcements list. Oddly, I can only seem to add the app to a page and not as a list (which is fine -- I just expected it to be like an Announcements list that shows differently).

Anyways, my main issue is that the default toolbar only has a button to Edit the list, which would bring a user directly to the list where they can then add an item. I have tried to edit the web part but I don't see any option to change the toolbar so that users can click Add Item and add new announcement tiles directly from the web part rather than having to go to the list. Am I missing something or is this not possible?